# StreamPlot Artifact

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

When using [`StreamPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamPlot.html) with two different ranges, one gives a plot artifact and it is not clear what it is trying to say.

If you plot

```
  StreamPlot[{1, (-x + x^2 + y^2)/(x^2*y*(-1 + x*y))}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

The plot is

[image: correct plot with streams]

If you slightly change the range

```
 StreamPlot[{1, (-x + x^2 + y^2)/(x^2*y*(-1 + x*y))}, {x, -1.64028, 1.71557}, {y, -1.64028, 1.71557}]
```

The plot is

[image: similar plot, but contains an upwards pointing red arrow where a downwards blue one was before close to the center of the plot]

What does the item circled in red represent? Is it just some unwanted artifact? Why is it a different color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set y->0.1 and draw the y component of the corresponding vector as a function of x:

```
Plot[(-x + x^2 + y^2)/(x^2*y*(-1 + x*y)) /. y -> 0.1, {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

You see that the y-component at the point x==0 is very small. And this is what the different color of the vector communicates.

Comment: Hmm - so is this showing that artifact StreamPlot[{1, (-x + x^2 + y^2)/(x^2*
     y*(-1 + x*y))}, {x, -.1, .1}, {y, -.5, .5}]?

Comment: It is not an artifact it is the color function.